# is my code messed up or is someone trying to hack site

Tags: wordpress, superfish

Im looking over the forms, if someone already spoke on this topic please share link. I keep getting messages saying users tried to access a non-existant page. Here is picture: http://screencast.com/t/gMmW7IahI3m

Im trying to see if i messed up somewhere with my super-fish script or if its a hacker trying to access the script for some vulnerability. I've come across people online saying there is a hack but i think it is something on my end. Just having a hard time finding any answers online.

Comment: as far as i know i installed the script correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my conjecture.

If you visit this page (the one from your logs):

```
http://www.peakworthy.com/randomly-awesome-moments-caught-by-ameteur-photographers/23/
```

And keep an eye on the network tab of your browser tools, you'll see that the page does in fact make a request to:

```
http://www.peakworthy.com/wp-content/themes/my-simone/js/superfish-settings.js?ver=6a68914e282a033f4f06420fddc1e005
```

The main superfish.js file is found in this directory, so I'm guessing the settings file is missing and needs to be added.

```
http://www.peakworthy.com/wp-content/themes/my-simone/js/
```

So in summary, nothing malicious... just a problem with your theme missing a file.

Comment: Thank you thats what i thought. appreciate the help. I should be able to find it.